# Linking external stylesheet to the page within an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, local

I've checked out plenty of other questions but still no luck.

I'm working on my local machine in chrome.

I've got welcome.html (main page) and test.html (iframe page)
then I have my style.css.

The Goal: Have my test.html as an iframe inside my welcome.html page. But have the iframe (test.html) be styled using jQuery.

So I have this in my welcome.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
var $head = $("iframe").contents().find("head");                
$head.append($("<link>", { rel: "stylesheet", href: "style.css", type: "text/css"     }));
});
</script>
```

and then this inside the body tag

```
<iframe name='iframe' id="iframe" src="test.html"></iframe>
```

iframe is working but no styles are being attached when I inspect the iframe.

Comment: i think your code not work because the `jquery` can't access to another page head,i think you should do it with ajax -not sure-

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: I'm developing locally @PatrickM that thread didn't solve my issue.

Comment: What are you using to develop? Just opening the files in a web browser? Do you have a server running? What browsers are you targeting? The simplest solution (and the only solution that will *always* work) is to just add the stylesheet to `test.html`. Anything more complicated is going to depend on implementation details - getting javascript working across iFrames is complicated and a security risk, so browsers have all sorts of guards against it.

Comment: Just locally no server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can't directly edit the iframe source? The simplest solution would be to just add the `<link>` tag there.

However, your real problem may be that it can't find the css file. The `src` attribute in the `<link>` tag needs to be relative to the location of the iframe. If the iframe is on some other domain, you'll need an absolute path (in your case maybe `"http://localhost/whatever/style.css"`).

Comment: All of this is in the same folder on my local machine.